# I am using gem exiftool to extract metadata how can i print that data in proper table format?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, hash, exiftool

I have used gem exiftool to extract metadata on my rails project but on my browser its printing like an array. I want to print it in proper keys and values format.
My code is this and its not working.

```
photo = Exiftool.new oldpath(myfile)
            photo1=photo.to_hash
            photo1.each_pair { |k, v| "#{k}:#{v}" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use prety print

```
require 'pp'

pp(photo.to_hash)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Novarg how can you say that "This does not provide an answer to the question."? It is.